# Need a delegate that returns me the next advice in textual form

Tags: ios, skmaps

I am looking for a delegate method that gets triggered when there's a new advice (like "turn left now") and that returns me that advice in a textual form. I found the `didChangeAdviceID` delegate method in  the `SKNavigationDelegate` but when I test it with;

```
navSettings.navigationType = SKNavigationTypeSimulation;
```

it gets triggered one time with `advice changed: -1` and that's it.

Also when I try to get the collection of all calculated advices with:

```
NSArray *adviceList = [[SKRoutingService sharedInstance] routeAdviceListWithDistanceFormat:SKDistanceFormatMetric];
for (SKRouteAdvice *advice in adviceList) {
    NSLog(@"%d: %@", [advice adviceID], [advice adviceInstruction]);
}
```

so that I can get the current advice by calling the index I don't get anything in the `adviceInstruction` property. It's simply empty. The id however is displayed properly (there's like 20 entries for my testing route).

Comment: If you develop a turn-by-turn navigation system, I imagine you can get the directions in any format you want.  Otherwise, it might be a good idea to specify how you're getting your turn-by-turn directions.

Comment: Sorry for the washy question. I updated it. Basically there is a collection of advices I can get (see the code above) but it's not working properly. Also the delegate method is not working as expected.

Comment: Have you read through the docs?  There's some stuff in there that I could guess at might be your problem, but I've never worked with any of this stuff and it seems like it'd be most efficient for you to just read through the docs yourself and see what you've missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [demo app](http://developer.skobbler.com/download/SKMaps_iOS_withOpenSourceDemo.zip) there is a demo of navigating a route with navigationType simulation (see the Routing & Navigation demo) and there you can have a look at all the callbacks being called during navigation.

Right now in the callbacks you won't get the current/next advice in text form but only in visual form (as a openGL generated picture) and audio form (as a audio advice).
In a future update (could be June) of the SDK there will also be text advices, something like:

```
void)routingService:(SKRoutingService *)routingService didChangeCurrentAdviceInstruction:(NSString *)currentAdviceInstruction nextAdviceInstruction:(NSString *)nextAdviceInstruction;
```

For the current version a list of routing directions can be retrieved once a route is calculated (e.g. http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec15) and there you can see “adviceInstructions” in the form of a string.

Though, during actual navigation, more info than just the one found in the routing directions will be presented to the user.

Comment: I'd be awesome if you commented or updated your answer once the update arrived :)

Comment: Btw do you know why the `adviceInstruction` property of SKRouteAdvice always seems to be empty? (streetName, id etc. are working fine)

Comment: I'll make a note to update the answer :)
Regarding your second question - could I have a code snippet? (maybe it deserves it's own stackoverflow question)